Proper way to shut down a Spring Boot application after a specific unit of work is completed
I have a number of Spring Boot services that are always running that perform several different kinds of tasks. For example I have one service that is reading from an Azure Service Bus queue using Spring Cloud Stream and then sending the message to a method in an @Service class. What I'm trying to do is ensure that the currently processing message is completed prior to allowing the application to shut down when it receives a SIGTERM from Kubernetes. We are trying to do this to prevent our data from ending up in an inconsistent state.
For this example, we read from the queue in our Application class:
@Bean
public Consumer<String> readMessage() {
    return json -> {
        try {
            long[] eventIds = new Gson().fromJson(json, long[].class);
            service.processMessage(eventIds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception in processing message..." + ex.getMessage());
        }
    };
}

We process the message here:
@Service
public class MessageService {

    //Autowired dependencies, etc.

    public void processMessage(long[] eventIds) throws Exception {
        // Perform work
        .
        .
        .
        // Now we can shut down safely
    }
}

I have already added the following Spring Settings:
spring.lifecycle.timeout-per-shutdown-phase=15s
server.shutdown=graceful

I have also added a PreStop hook that just does a sleep to the lifecycle on the container in my deployment.yaml but all this does is delays sending the SIGTERM to the pod that is shutting down:
lifecycle:
   preStop:
      exec:
         command: ["sh", "-c", "sleep 15"]

This doesn't seem to help on it's own and instead just shuts the service down immediately regardless of what processing is happening. I am thinking that adding an event listener on the ContextClosedEvent is the way to go, but I'm still struggling to find a way, other than putting a Thread.sleep for some arbitrary time that should be long enough in the EventListener
@Component
public class ShutdownListener {

    @Autowired
    private BindingsEndpoint bindingsEndpoint;
    
    @EventListener(ContextClosedEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationShutdown() {
        // Stop reading more messages from the queue
        bindingsEndpoint.changeState("binding-name",State.STOPPED);
        // Don't want to do this, but instead wait for the currently processing message to finish
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        ThisApplication.ctx.close();
    }
}

Is there a built in Spring way to know when the processing has stopped? This is one example, but I also have other services that are making DB calls on a timer, or exposing endpoints for other apps to send work to. I'm hoping there is some generic way to accomplish what I'm looking for. If there is not, how can I have some custom code have a way to notify the application that it is done with it's current unit of work.

ThreadPoolExecutor#awaitTermination(...) is designed for it
In case you haven't specified custom TaskExecutors try to add these properties:
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.execution.shutdown.await-termination-period=15s

spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination=true
spring.task.scheduling.shutdown.await-termination-period=15s

If you have custom Executor bean, for example ThreadPoolTaskExecutor, tune it like this:
@Bean(name = "customExecutor")
public Executor executor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    taskExecutor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(15);
    // other configurations
    taskExecutor.initialize();
    return taskExecutor;
}

On shutdown hook Spring gets all it's ThreadPoolExecutor beans and call their shutdown(). It only stops receiving new tasks though, but don't wait for submitted tasks get finished.

So if I don't need a custom executor (since I only want this to ensure my processing method completed before shutdown), I can just add the properties, use the EnableAsync annotation on my main class and the Async annotation on my processMessage() method? Does Spring automatically create an executor when needed?

In your case this is not necessary. @Async is useful when you have to do multiple things simultaneously, for example, send few HTTP requests and collect the result. Your processMessage flow seems straightforward and probably will be called from default ThreadPoolExecutor (but still depends on a message handler's configuration). So just properties should enough

Thank you for the clear and concise answers here! I'm going to implement this and try it out.
